# Getting one row per group in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I often want to process one row of a data.table at a time.  I've been using

```
d[, j, by=rownames(d)]
```

but this doesn't always seem to work (sometimes getting an error message about by appearing to evaluate to column names), and in any case isn't a very clean expression of what I'm trying to do.

Let me give a specific example.

```
d = data.table(a=c(1,2),b=c(3,4))
f = function(x,y) x[1]+y[1] #expects length 1 vectors x and y and adds them
d[, id := 1:.N]
d[, f(a,b), by=id]
d[, id := NULL]
```

The situation is that I have a function f that is not vectorized.  I've decorated d with an id column so I can process one row at a time. I'm looking for a better way to do this.

Here's another example, without a function f:

```
d[, list(a=a,b=b,s=a:b), by = id]
d[, id := NULL]
```

Comment: `d[, j, by=rownames(d)][, rownames:=NULL][]` :-/

Comment: If you "often want to process one row of a data.table at a time", you should think really hard if there isn't a better (read more efficient) alternative to your general approach.

Comment: @DavidR Possibly `d[, j, by=.I]`?

Comment: @nrussell, I think that makes a single group out of the whole data table, which is equivalent to no by at all.

Comment: R is generally a vectorized language and thus designed to work with vectors, rather by row (see @Rolands comment). If you still insist to do stuff by row, I don't see any problem in creating an index by reference using  `d[, id := .I]` (it shouldn't be time consuming even for a huge data set) and then using it as you already do. Though, by row operations are usually deemed to be very inefficient for data sets bigger than `1e6` because you are basically creating `1e6`+ distinct groups.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I guess we could set the key to be id to make the grouping fast.  I'm guessing there isn't a better approach at the moment, so you can make this an answer if you want...

Comment: You are using data.table as an alternative to a `for` loop. Just like with a `for` loop, the loop itself is fast. What you do inside the loop consumes the time. Optimize your function as much as possible. If it's still too slow due to the repeated function calls, you could implement the whole loop inside your function using Rcpp.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job, following the example I found at https://arelbundock.com/posts/datatable_rowwise/

```
# Your example data frame and function 
d = data.table(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4))
f <- function(x, y) {x[1] + y[1]}

# Try the Map() function for row-wise operations
d[, z := Map(f, a, b)]
```

produces

```
#>    a b z
#> 1: 1 3 4
#> 2: 2 4 6
```